# is there an easy way to change a css value based on the current value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
    if ($( "#htmlBox" ).css("display") == "block") {
        $( "#htmlBox" ).css("display", "none");
    } else {
        $( "#htmlBox" ).css("display", "block");
    }
```

I wonder what's the quicker way to toggle between these two values.

Comment: Is this code triggered by an event? When do you run it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can just use `toggle()` to switch back and forth between visible and hidden display states:

```
$("#htmlBox").toggle();
```

If you did want to use `css()` for this then you can supply the new value in a function which you can use to execute whatever logic you need. This function also accepts the current value as an argument:

```
$('#htmlBox').css('display', function(i, state) {
  return state === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

Generally speaking, it's best to avoid using `css()` where possible as UI styling should be kept solely in CSS. Putting it in JS can lead to maintenance issues. When done in that manner, it would be better to use `toggleClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using visibility in your example and as such, as already suggested, `toggle()` works best, to shorten your initial code, assuming other CSS examples you can use the [**Ternary Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Though, yes, in your specific case, `toggle()` is best!

```
$("#htmlBox").css("display", $("#htmlBox").css("display") == "block" ? "none" : "block");
```

Comment: Besides, you're traversing the DOM twice and building two identical jQuery objects by calling `$("#htmlBox")` twice

Comment: I’ll have to study the ternary operator, seems a good way to cut a lot of code. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, indeed. OP should be using separate classes and toggle between them to begin with instead of using `.css()`. Code provided in answers suggest solutions are are not to be taken verbatim for copy-pasta but should be incorporated into OPs code as needed using their coding standards off course.